Sealed classes are not supported as program classes
I installed a jitpack package on the android side in a flutter package. The package seems to have been added without any problems, but I am getting the following error. What exactly is this error? What is the reason and solution? What is the reason and solution? What is the reason and solution?
ERROR:/Users/volkanustekidag/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/035b376a3ef8108757fc2829f1bfe6ad/transformed/jetified-all-documents-reader-1.0.7-runtime.jar: D8: com.android.tools.r8.internal.Hc: Sealed classes are not supported as program classes

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform all-documents-reader-1.0.7.aar (com.github.ahmadullahpk:all-documents-reader:1.0.7) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=androidJvm}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/volkanustekidag/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/035b376a3ef8108757fc2829f1bfe6ad/transformed/jetified-all-documents-reader-1.0.7-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

My build.gradle
group = "com.volkan.document_reader"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.9.25"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url("https://jcenter.bintray.com")
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'  // en son sürümü kontrol edin
        classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.2.42")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

android {
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace = "com.volkan.document_reader"
    }

    compileSdk = 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
        test.java.srcDirs += "src/test/kotlin"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()

            testLogging {
                events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
                outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
                showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:5.0.0")
    implementation("com.github.ahmadullahpk:all-documents-reader:1.0.7")
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}

My settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url ("https://jcenter.bintray.com")
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
        }


    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url("https://jcenter.bintray.com")
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
        }

    }
}


rootProject.name = 'document_reader'
include ":app"

